# Emacs shell slow compile

Tags: shell

So I've been searching around for this particular problem and apparently I found no solutions.

There are posts on reddit about this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3scsak/incredibly_slow_comint_eg_shell_compile_output_on/.

But still no solution.  The problem is simple: emacs shell is really bad when you run codes that display lots of text in the shell.

I run fluids simulations and the difference between running the code via emacs' shell and VS code's shell is like day and night. This is what I get running the same test case (1D so not very intensive)

- VS code embedded shell: 10 seconds.
- Emacs shell: more than 1 minute and still running....

Anyone experiences issue when compiling, running code that outputs lots of text? I need to see the outputs as the code runs.

Comment: Have you tried using `M-x compile` or evaluating `(compile COMMAND-LINE)`; and, does that resolve your speed issues when compiling?  Of course, it is not a shell, but may be a viable alternative -- it is especially useful when it comes to jumping to the relevant section of the source code from the compilation buffer.

Comment: Using M-x compile is just as slow.

Comment: What's VS? How big is "lots of text"?

Comment: VS code: visual studio code, another text editor.  The terminal that I run in this application to run my code is faster than the shell/terminal in emacs.   "Lots of text" in my scenario is around 10 lines per screen, and those 10 lines will keep updating as the code runs

Comment: sounds like your output is getting buffered. you'll need to modify your program to ensure its output is unbuffered. also for `shell`, `eshell`, `term`, and `ansi-term` and see how they deal with buffered/unbuffered text.